# shared mailbox "send as" not working for internal recipients

Tags: exchangeonline

We created a new shared mailbox in Exchange Online and assigned users Full Access and Send As rights. When those users send to external email addresses as the shared mailbox, it works. But when they try to send to an internal users, they get an NDR (see below).

All of my research points to setting up the Send As permissions correctly. But the permissions are correct.

Any other ideas?

```
Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

      Subject:  
      Sent: 1/3/2024 12:04 PM

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

      xxxxxxx xxxxxx on 1/3/2024 12:04 PM
            This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user. 

__________________________________________________

Diagnostic information for administrators:
__________________________________________________

Error is [0x80070005-0x000004dc-0x00000524].

Exchange response headers:
    request-id: bf49d092-1200-83e6-25e7-396c4bdfa92b
    X-ServerApplication: Exchange/15.20.7159.005
    X-FEServer: BN0PR10CA0018
    X-CalculatedBETarget: SA1PR17MB5508.namprd17.prod.outlook.com
    X-RequestId: {45C6FF50-FBD4-41AA-B096-AB2E1793E9E2}:558
    X-ClientInfo: {4950CDA0-3BE9-48AF-9867-53663DCDCB07}:217520026
    X-ElapsedTime: 89
    X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
    X-ResponseCode: 0
    X-RequestType: Execute
__________________________________________________

ROPs Summary:

    0: ropRelease (1) Processed(1) Completed(0)
        ROP result: 0
        Response codes: 0
    1: ropSetProps (10) Processed(1) Completed(0)
        ROP result: 0
        Response codes: 0
    2: ropSetProps (10) Processed(1) Completed(0)
        ROP result: 0
        Response codes: 0
    3: ropFlushRecipients (14) Processed(1) Completed(0)
        ROP result: 0
        Response codes: 0
    4: ropSetProps (10) Processed(1) Completed(0)
        ROP result: 0
        Response codes: 0
    5: ropTransportSend (74) Processed(1) Completed(0)
        ROP result: 0
        Response codes: 1244
__________________________________________________

Response Exceptions:

ROP Index: 5
ROP Associated: ropTransportSend (74)
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.SendAsDeniedException: Can't send message.
 ---> Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied: MapiExceptionSendAsDenied: Unable to send message. (hr=0x80070005, ec=1244)
0.35250:11020000, 1.36674:01000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:00000000, 1.36674:01000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:05000000, 1.44866:00000000, 1.36674:7A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:08000000, 1.44866:00140000, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:19000000, 1.44866:362E0000, 1.36674:0E000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:522E0000, 1.44866:11020000, 16.55847:5E160000, 17.43559:0000000034020000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140FF79B0300001015000000, 20.50032:140FF79B7D17F01FA4000000, 0.53414:12000000, 0.35180:14000000, 255.23226:15000000, 255.27962:7A000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:28000000, 0.35250:4D020000, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:10000000, 1.36674:4A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:15000000, 1.44866:00000000, 16.55847:76000000, 17.43559:00000000A8030000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140FF79B030000007B000000, 20.50032:140FF79B7D1770200A00403A, 0.53414:80000000, 0.35180:6B020000, 255.23226:0A00773A, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:4A000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.44949:A0000000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:B5000000, 0.38698:47000000, 1.41134:47000000, 0.37692:87000000, 0.37948:87000000, 5.33852:00000000534D545000000000, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:01000000018A4AD700000000, 7.57132:00000000000000001A010480, 4.39640:DC040000, 1.63016:4A000000, 8.45434:27FDD548F1C0104695841D07F5BAFDB100000000, 1.46798:13000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E373135392E3030353A534131505231374D42353530383A35623030303435612D646263372D346161662D383432332D3164636333393530333366633A39333334383A2E4E455420362E302E3235001A010480, 7.51330:DA84ABF07D0CDC081A010480, 0.39570:00000000, 1.55954:0A000000, 1.33010:0A000000, 2.54258:00000000, 0.40002:00000000, 1.56562:00000000, 1.33010:0A000000, 2.54258:00000000, 0.40002:00000000, 1.56562:00000000, 1.64146:4A000000, 1.33010:4A000000, 2.54258:DC040000, 1.33010:4A000000, 2.54258:DC040000, 255.1750:0A001870, 255.31418:80030400, 0.22753:B9000000, 255.21817:DC040000, 0.34722:43010000, 4.51106:DC040000, 0.41890:0B00F410, 4.58274:DC040000, 0.59285:C7000000, 4.46997:DC040000
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.InternalThrowIfErrorOrWarning(String message, Int32 hresult, Boolean allowWarnings, Int32 ec, DiagnosticContext diagCtx, Exception innerException, MapiStore mapiStore)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hresult, IExInterface iUnknown, Exception innerException, MapiStore mapiStore)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiMessage.Implement_TransportSendMessage(PropValue[]& propsToReturn)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiMessage.TransportSendMessage(PropValue[]& propsToReturn)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.StoreObjects.MapiAccessorExtensionMethods.TransportSendMessage(IStoreSession storeSession, Object mapiObject, ExTimeZone timezone, PropValue[]& mapiPropValues)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.StoreObjects.MapiAccessorExtensionMethods.TransportSendMessage(IStoreSession storeSession, Object mapiObject, ExTimeZone timezone, PropValue[]& mapiPropValues)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.CoreItem.TransportSend(PropertyDefinition[]& properties, Object[]& values)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.Message.TransportSend()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.RopHandler.<>c__DisplayClass156_0.<TransportSend>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.ExceptionTranslator.TryExecuteCatchAndTranslateExceptions[TResult](Func`1 protectedCode, Func`2 errorCodeExtractor, Boolean noThrow, TResult& result, Exception& exception, ErrorCode& errorCode)


Transport-Send failed: failure enum(25), HResult(0x00000000), EC(1244).
Transport-Send failed: failure enum(22), HResult(0x00000000), EC(1244).
Submit-Message failed: message id(21), failure enum(13), HResult(0x80070005), EC(1244).
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have already set up the Send As permissions correctly, but the issue persists. Here are some additional steps you can try:

Ensure that the Global Address List (GAL) is updated. You can do this by downloading the Offline Address Book in Outlook desktop. Go to Send/Receive > Send/Receive Groups > Download Address Book, then click OK.

Try sending an email from the shared mailbox using Outlook Web Access (OWA). Create a new email and select the user that has the correct permission level from the Show from field. If the email sends successfully, the issue may be with the Outlook desktop client.

Check if the users have the Send As permission for the shared mailbox. If not, grant them the permission. For information on how to do this, see Manage permissions for recipients.

If the issue persists, try updating the address book by going to the Send/Receive tab and clicking on Send-Receive Groups > Download Address Book. After clicking on OK, try sending again from Outlook using your shared mailbox.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/365-send-as-permissions-not-working/1c866141-1777-4faf-86e4-aa933b23d6fe